# How can I drag and drop to offset an element in a selenium test so that it will work on FireFox

Tags: selenium, firefox, browser, browserstack

When I run on FireFox browser a selenium test that is trying to move an element from its location to another using the function DragAndDropToOffset in Actions Class it fails with the following exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: data did not match any variant of untagged enum PointerActionItem at line...

When I'm trying to use DragAndDrop function that moves one element to the location of another instead of DragAndDropToOffset it works well.

I'm using Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support of version=2.48.2.0

The code that I tried and faild:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using Actions = OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions;

public void MyDragAndDropOffset(IWebElement source, int offsetX, int offsetY, RemoteWebDriver driver)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.DragAndDropToOffset(source, offsetX, offsetY).Build().Perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using CSharp to execute the tests. You can review details on the exception in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I assume that the exception has been thrown from one of the operations that are done on the driver as part from the drag and drop function and I'm not exposed to that.